# Where is the InfoPath self-signed certificate store?

Tags: 2010, infopath, certificate

I used InfoPath 2010 to create a self-signed certificate (which I can see in InfoPath when I go to sign my code).  Where is that stored?  Even after a refresh, I can't find that certificate in the MMC certificate snap-in.

[edit] Okay, I realize now that I have to "install" the certificate in order to see it in the snap-in.  Yet, I still don't know where InfoPath saves the certificates.

I've poked around in Windows, but can't find them anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe InfoPath saves them to a store or directory. A self signed, as far as I knew, does not meet the application criteria, and can only be used for testing. The Cert will only be put into that store if it is issued by the Certification Authority.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask where Infopath Designer store digital code signing certicate when you click **Create certificate...** button, then it is stored in Certificates < Personal < Certificates - Current User < run **certmgr.msc** (from command line or command interpreter window cmd)

You can export it there (menu Action > All Tasks > Export...)

[image]

Comment: Hello, Mr. Gennady.  I looked there, but, like I said in my question, I can't find it there.  I don't think the certificate will appear in the certmgr.msc unless it be installed.  I was wondering where Infopath was keeping it.